# DBFit Fitnesse email notification

Tags: email, notifications, fitnesse, dbfit

I would like to send out an email notification from DBFit/Fitnesse when a test suite execution completes with some failed tests.
I am unable to find any working solution, has anyone got one?

Answer (score 0):

How do you run your tests?

I run tests on a build server and have that e-mail me and my team when one or more tests fail. 
I use FitNesse's jUnit runner to execute the tests as a project automatically. Build servers have standard features to detect failed jUnit tests and notify people of those.

Comment: At the moment we simply run the test suite from the browser. May you provide further details on how to implement your methodology?

Comment: Are you at all aware of build servers, do you have one available already? I've got a project on GitHub that provides a FitNesse baseline that can easily be run with a build server (https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki#2-run-on-build-server). You could take this and add your DbFit tests to that.

Comment: Thank you but it looks pretty complex to integrate with the DBFit fitnesse standaloone.  I have managed to achieve what I need with a compination of wget and powershell.